# Disable auto hide subtitle ios storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, cell

How to set cell (Right Detail) to not hide subtitle after long title text. I don't use Auto Layout and Size Classes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQJXa.jpg

Comment: try something like this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `[cell bringSubviewToFront:detailTextLabel]`

Comment: I think you should set the numberOfLines = 0 and preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the left label programatically in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

If solution you look for is showing the rest of the line in the next line, you may try this
`cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`